# error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - style.scss

Tags: css, ubuntu, sass, drupal

so i am using sass in a Drupal project in Ubuntu ,
I am trying to watch the scss file using this command

`sass --watch style.scss:style.css` ,

from the web root of the project but i got this error

`error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - style.scss`

This is my file structure:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lXJE.png)